# XStream - using a property setter instead of direct field access

Tags: javabeans, xstream, getter-setter

I'm trying to load an object from XML using XStream.
By default XStream seems to use direct field access. Thus, when you map a field named 'rolesAsString' to an alias named 'roles', it will take the value from the 'roles' tag and try to set it directly to your 'rolesAsString' field in your class. This works in most cases, but not in my case.

Here is the XML relevant for the question:
`<principal name="admin" roles="role1, role2, role3">`

Here is the class:

`public class Principal {
    private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
    public Set<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }`

```
public void setRolesAsString(String roles) {
    for (String role : roles.split(",")) {
        role = role.trim();
        if (!"".equals(role)) { //ignore empty string roles
            this.roles.add(role);
        }
    }
}

public String getRolesAsString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (String role : roles) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            result.append(", ");
        }
        result.append(role);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

I am trying to make XStream call setRolesAsString when loading the configuration from the xml file, instead of trying to connect directly to the roles field.

I have tried doing that with JavaBeanConverter converter, but I can't make it work. Code I'm using for that is:

`configParser.registerLocalConverter(Principal.class, "roles", new JavaBeanConverter(configParser.getMapper()) {
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz) {
        return true;//should make XStream to always use this converter for that field.
    }
});`

configParser.aliasAttribute(Resource.class, "roles", "roles");

Any idea where I'm going wrong on this?

Thanks,
Stef.

Comment: there has to be a way to do this ... otherwise XStream is limiting how you can define your classes internally (e.g. have a field for each tag/attribute). Adapting your domain objects to work with a framework  shouldn't be required for good frameworks ... Thoughtworks is quite good at software architecture, thus I'm sure this was covered somehow ... just not sure how.

Comment: This can be done in JAXB using `@XmlAccessorType`.  If you are interested in using a JAXB implementation (Metro, MOXy, JaxMe, etc) instead of XStream, just let me know.  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise, I've seen your blog when searching for an answer before posting here (nice presentation ;) ). Unfortunately, the project is using XStream in some other places (I just took it over). I might migrate it to JAXB, but at this moment it wouldn't make sense to do so, until I fully understand the implications of removing XStream. At the same time, I wouldn't like to design the classes to work with a framework ... tough :). Anyway, this seems like a very trivial task, I can't believe it's not covered by XStream.

Comment: In case you are interested here is a post I wrote about JAXB and field/property access: http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html